# An alternative to creating tables that only store default data?

Tags: sql, database

I have a small database where most of my tables have a duplicate table whose sole purpose is to hold default data. For example I have "tableA" and "default_TableA" and default_TableA may have the following values:

```
default_TableA

id | name
----------
1  | John
2  | Mark
```

The purpose of this is so that values can be added to tableA and in the event that I need to reset tableA to the default values, I can clear it then copy the values from default_TableA.

My question is if there is a better way to get this done or if it's better for the application to store the default values somewhere and then insert them into the table when needed?

My apologies if my question isn't clear or if it's already been asked. I wasn't sure how to google this question and what I've found doesn't really answer my question. If you have a link to similar question that's already been answered I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: I would store them in a separate database, rather than in the same database.

Comment: A simple .SQL file per table would suffice. Most SQL workbenches allow you to export just the data and import just the data. You're approach while not bad, clutters the database with a second functionality.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll try these suggestions and see what works for me